# Auto login to GeoServer using REST API

Tags: geoserver, authentication

Is there a way to auto login to GeoServer using the REST API? I need to use REST API to login to GeoServer and open logged in page of GeoServer using REST API.

Comment: what do you mean by auto login? you need to authenticate each REST request as it is stateless

Comment: Yes exactly. Aftre sending username and password in post request should get me to the geoserver welcome page with user (username sent in param) logged in

Comment: that isn't how rest works

Comment: Yes but i need not any layer upload, create workspace etc using rest. Just need to login to geoserver using username and password. Any example rest api for that?

Comment: **that isn't how rest works** the REST api is solely for managing the configuration of GeoServer

Comment: Can you please share an example request to get into geoserver welcome page?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/90020/discussion-between-user123-and-ian-turton).